# How do I get javaws to recognize and use alternate JREs that I have installed?

Tags: java

I have multiple JDKs installed. For one particular JNLP I need to make sure it is run with some older JRE. The Java Control Panel only recognises the latest version. How do I make it see the others and use them?

```
ls /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/
1.6.0.jdk       jdk1.7.0_80.jdk     jdk1.8.0_102.jdk    jdk1.8.0_71.jdk     jdk1.8.0_92.jdk
```

Comment: Related: [Starting Java Webstart App with older installed JRE Version](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24425159/starting-java-webstart-app-with-older-installed-jre-version). Try this answer. If it doesn't work please report back.

Comment: No, the problem is that javaws does not find the java executable. It turns out that if I use the java 1.6 macaws it works, but there is no way to specify a java 1.7 JRE still.

Comment: Is the jnlp available? Or is it some commercial/internal app?

Comment: It's commercial/internal, yes, unfortunately. But It seems to me that the problem is more on the client side of things.